# Apigee - Issue while configuring an API Proxy

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, wsdl, apigee

I'm looking for a way to expose my customer's WCF Services as REST Services (and create all the security stack to support claims / oauth authentication and authorization)
I'm working on 2 different approach to do so:

1. Create a new REST Service which will act as a proxy to
   expose my WCF Service as REST Services (11 services / 130 web methods to
   migrate...) and secure it using an IP STS / RS STS
2. Use a existing product like Apigee which will do all those job for me and even more feature than initially planned.

I'm trying to play with Apigee first, but I'm facing an issue while creating the API Proxy.

I've deployed a simple WCF Service (with only 2 methods) on a Windows Azure VM exposed in basicHttp (which works as expected - means I test it in a Console app successfully, even when the client app is located outside my Azure's VM -).

Problem comes when I follow the Apigee workflow to expose it as a REST Service. I try to fetch service's wsdl on Apigee portal and got following error:

**Error: Cannot invoke method getOperation() on null object**

Does someone know where the issue come from ? I don't have much information from Apigee portal.
I already validate my wsdl through http://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/ but everything looks fine...
Meantime, Amazone webservice works fine on Apigee and generate the REST Service so problem seems to come from my service's WSDL

Comment: Can you post a link to your WSDL here? May be you can use http://pastebin.com/

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed and will be included in the next release (R24.4).  If you still have any problems with the new release, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I recently got a similar error in the most recent version of Apigee (Version 141029).

The error: "Fetch WSDL Error: Cannot invoke method startsWith() on null object".

The fix was to rename my local file from "somename.xml" to "somename.wsdl".