# Apigee Fetch WSDL Error: Cannot invoke method startsWith() on null object

Tags: apigee

I am getting the below error when i am creating a API proxy on free Apigee cloud environment :

Fetch WSDL Error: Cannot invoke method startsWith() on null object

A similar issues was reported here
[Apigee - Issue while configuring an API Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267853/apigee-issue-while-configuring-an-api-proxy)

I have kept the wsdl here
http://pastebin.com/tavinD2n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got resolved .  The wsdl file was named as XXX.WSDL , i changed it to XXX.wsdl and it worked. Strange isn't it?  Should it be case sensitive?